# G-invariants of a group

Tags: finite-groups

Let $\varphi:G\to GL(V)$ be a representation of a finite group $G$. Define the subspace $$V^G=\{v\in V\mid\text{for all } g\in G,gv=v\}.$$  How can I show that $V^G$ is a $G$-invariant subspace.

Comment: There is nothing to show. It is just by definition of $G$-invariant and $V^G$.

Comment: Think what you want to show: "If $v\in V^G$ and $g\in G$, then $gv\in V^G$"